# How do i get the value of an object in a object string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

Hello there im kinda new to this so what I want to do is this:

```
var Obj = {
    "Key": {
        "Key2": "Value"
    }
}

var path = ["Key","Key2"]
```

How can I get "Value" of Obj.Key.Key2 by using the path variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/reduce) for this:

```js
const value = path.reduce((accum, key) => accum[key], string)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several approaches. First, you can use a loop to traverse the path step by step as follows:

```js
const obj = { "string2": { "value": "Message" } };
const path = [ "string2", "value" ];

let output = obj;
path.forEach(key => {
    output = output[key];
});

console.log( output );
```

**RECURSION**

```js
const obj = { "string2": { "value": "Message" } };
const path = [ "string2", "value" ];

const trav = (o,p,i) => (i < p.length - 1) ? trav(o[p[i]],p,i+1) : o[p[i]];

console.log( trav(obj,path,0) );
```

**new Function**

```js
const obj = { "string2": { "value": "Message" } };
const path = [ "string2", "value" ];

const output = (new Function(`return (obj.${path.join('.')})`))();

console.log( output );
```