# Find value in array or object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I want to find a value in a array with a path.

Example:

```
var object = {
              "value1": [
                {
                  "valueinarray": "myvalue"
                }
              ]
            }
```

```
var array = [
              {
                "value1": {
                  "value2": [
                    {
                      "valueinarray": "myvalue"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
```

Now I want to get myvalue with a path like value1[0] or [0].value2[0]

I asked a similar question but it dosnt work with array: [How do i get the value of an object in a object string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879311/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-an-object-in-a-object-string)

Comment: if you are using a library like lodash it has the `get` method

Answer (score -2, accepted):

comment from cmgchess was the solution

```js
var object = { "firstKey": { "SomeName": "SomeValue" } }
var path = "firstKey.SomeName"

const lodash = require("lodash")
lodash.get(object, path) // SomeValue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with JS object as below then it's an incorrect object

> var array = [    "value1": {
> "value2": [
> "valueinarray": "myvalue"
> ]
> }  ]

Object can be refactored as

> var array = [    {
> "value2": [
> {"valueinarray": "myvalue"}
> ]
> }  ]

And values can be fetched as below

> array[0].value2[0]

Not sure if thats your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax of assigning value to the array is wrong. You need to use curly bracket { } for putting key value pair in an array. For example : value2: [ { "valueinarray": "myvalue"} ].

```js
var object = {
              "value1": [
                {
                  "valueinarray": "myvalue"
                }
              ]
            }

console.log(object.value1[0].valueinarray);

var array = [
              {
                "value1": {
                  "value2": [
                    {
                      "valueinarray": "myvalue"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
            
console.log(array[0].value1.value2[0].valueinarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(object.value1[0].valueinarray);
var array = [{"value2": ["myvalue"]}];
console.log(array[0]['value2'][0]);
```